# How to reload a jstree from local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, jstree

I am using jstree to access an xml. I need to save the nodes created,etc in the tree to local storage.
So, what I'm doing right now is, when a node is created, I convert an instance of the tree to json form using 'get_json' and then using 'JSON.stringify', I convert it to a json string. I save this json string to local storage as 'SavedTree'.

```
  .bind('create_node.jstree', function(e, data){
   var jsonForm =$('#treeContainer').jstree('get_json', -1);
   localStorage.setItem('SavedTree', JSON.stringify(jsonForm)); 
   })
};
```

When I retrieve 'SavedTree' from localStorage, I parse it to convert the string back to json:

```
var NewTree = localStorage.getItem('SavedTree');
var NewTree = JSON.parse(NewTree);
```

'NewTree' is in Json form. How do I convert it back to an instance of the tree so that I can use it as 'data' in the below code ?

```
  ("#treeContainer").jstree({
    "json_data" : {
      "data": data
      "progressive_render":"true"
        },
    "plugins": [ "json_data", "contextmenu", "crrm", "dnd", "unique"],
  })
```

I am new to javascript so this may be a silly question but any advice on how to proceed will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the `state` plugin not do what you want?

Comment: Does n't the state plugin just remember which nodes are opened / closed ?

Comment: I need to save the tree when a node is created / deleted,etc.

Comment: I don't know whether `state` saves new nodes. I'd have assumed it did if it really was saving the state. The documentation doesn't mention it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This line is weird:

```
var NewTree = localStorage.getItem('SavedTree', JSON.parse(SavedTree));
```

`getItem` doesn't have a 2nd argument.

I think you want:

```
var NewTree = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SavedTree'));
```

Comment: Oh yea my bad, in my code I've got "getItem" and "JSON.parse" as two seperate statements, I tried to combine them in the question and made a slip. :)

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to use the json data to rebuild the tree though ?